# Why is a secondary transformer winding for VT filament heater connected to rectified output?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, ac, rectifier, vacuum-tube

Ok I know this is a pretty narrow question. I'm learning about vaccum tubes, and I think I have the basics down, but this particular setup is confusing me. See the attached picture.

[image]

In the given picture, we can see that the negative rectified output line connects to both the main secondary winding *and* the low voltage winding for the cathode heating. Why?

Unless I misunderstand something, the cathode heater is a complete circuit. Why does the rectified output need to connect back to the center-tap of the low-voltage winding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if the heater isn't earthed to a common ground, it will accumulate static charge, the field of which will bias the plate, causing the rectifier to not work correctly, and causing emitter-heater leakage.

Answer (score 1):

It is acting like a diode, the filament is the cathode connection.  This was common in the previous vacuum tube erera, it saved a pin. Careful if you build it, they can give you a nasty shock. the center tap evens the ware on the filament and helps reduce hum.

Comment: According to a GE datasheet, the 6W6GT IS a diode.  In that circuit, the cathode is the positive output.  The filament is insulated from the cathode.

Answer (score -2):

The 6w4GT tube is a direct heated dual triode. That thing connected to DC output plus is the control grid. The cathode and the filament are the same thing.

Comment: According to a GE datasheet, the 6W4GT is a diode - certainly not a dual triode.  With the heater negative relative to the cathode it can withstand 500 volts between heater and cathode.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The 6W4GT is a diode intended for use in a half-wave rectifier circuit.

Comment: Hmm. Where did I get that wrong number key from yesterday? You are both right, the 6W4GT is a indirect heated triode.

Comment: You mean diode?

Comment: Yeah, diode. Hrm.